# Symfony attributes routes not taken into account

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony5

I have an existing Symfony 5.2 application running on PHP 8 that uses YAML config for routes.

I'd like to convert it to use attributes instead. I added a `config/routes/annotations.yaml` file:

```yaml
controllers:
  resource: ../../src/UserInterface/Web/
  type: annotation

kernel:
  resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
  type: annotation
```

(yes, my controllers are under `src/UserInterface/Web`!)

I removed my routes from my `.yaml` config files, and added attributes to controllers:

```php
...
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function index(Request $request): Response { ... }
}
```

But my home page now displays the "Welcome to Symfony" page. I tried:

```
bin/console debug:router
```

but it does not display the `homepage` route. I tried using Doctrine annotations instead:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function index(Request $request): Response { ... }
```

with no luck either. I tried clearing the cache:

```
bin/console cache:clear
```

But the issue persists. **What did I miss?**

Comment: You still need to configure your controller as type: annotation. This feature only change the way you declare your routes inside the controllers classes (using attribute instead).

Comment: @yceruto I'm not sure what you're suggesting here..?

Comment: You have somthing else going on.  I made a fresh 5.2.6 project, added your UserInterface\Web\HomeController as well as your route attribute.  Tweaked annotations.yaml and the homepage route showed up in debug:router.  Maybe try the ever popular cache clearing.  I assume you are using PHP 8 as well.

Comment: @Cerad, using PHP 8, and cleared cache already. Should've mentioned it.

Comment: The fact that you said you 'added' an annotations.yaml file is perhaps a clue.  If you start with the website-skeleton then you should already have an annotations.yaml file in the config/routes directory.  It's possible you started with just the skeleton?  Might need to install the annotations stuff.

Comment: @Cerad Probably, I inherited a large project with lots of config.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-as-attributes-or-annotations might help.  Never been a big fan of route annotations myself.  If you already have a working yaml based project then I personally would just keep it.

Comment: Please share your `composer.json` file

Comment: @BenMorel I'd take a look at  ../../src/Kernel.php. Someone could potentially alter the way routes are handled in the configureRoutes method. 
Use this https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/main/src/Kernel.php or a fresh Symfony5.2 app as a reference for comparison.

Comment: @nemanjacucurevic Indeed, my `Kernel.php` was missing this line: `$routes->import('../config/{routes}/*.yaml');` in `configureRoutes()`. It works now! Please add this as an answer and I'll give you the bounty ;)

Comment: @yceruto, you mean to say, even if I use PHP 8's attribute, I still need to install `annotations`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOTE: the comment that turned out to be the correct answer to the question was an assumption based on the provided info and the discussion about the cache being cleared.

The fact that the route was not listed after running:

```
bin/console debug:router
```

Is a clue that Kernel::configureRoutes() method found in ../../src/Kernel.php was tampered in some way.

**The [default method implementation](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/1155cce56195fc3b42e9e0b7213ecda8ae4414e6/src/Kernel.php#L36) was missing the following line of code:**

```
$routes->import('../config/{routes}/*.yaml');
```

As confirmed by the author of the question.

Comment: If you use attributes to tell Symfony about a route using `#[Route('/login', name: 'login')]`, don't forget to include `Route` class via `use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;` Without it Symfony didn't recognize my attribute-based routes.